# "Syntax error: Operator expected" with CLPFD Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, collatz

I'm reading The Power Of Prolog, and have got as far as the section on the [Collatz sequence](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/concepts).

I copied and pasted the code from there, adding the appropriate `use_module` line before...

```
use_module(library(clpfd)).

hailstone(N, N).
hailstone(N0, N) :-
   N0 #= 2*N1,    % Error
   N0 #> 1,       % ensures termination
   hailstone(N1, N).
hailstone(N0, N) :-
   N0 #= 2*_ + 1, % Error
   N0 #> 1,       % ensures termination
   N1 #= 3*N0 + 1,
   hailstone(N1, N).
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get an error "*hailstone.pl:nn:10: Syntax error: Operator expected*" on the two lines commented above.

Anyone any idea what the error is, and why I get it? As you can see, I'm including the CLPFD module, so it should recognise `#=` as an operator.

I tried using `library(clpfd).` instead of the first line, but it didn't make any difference.

I'm using SWI-Prolog in case it makes any difference. Thanks.

Comment: You should be using `:- use_module...`, as at https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html

Comment: Ah, amazing how easy it is to miss these little subtleties! Obvious now you point it out. Ill get there in the end :) Thanks very much.

Comment: @brebs Not sure what you mean. Please can you explain. Thanks

Comment: I edited your code to ensure termination of e.g. `?- hailstone(1, N).`